# Failing an attempt to cast Mists of Releh

Tags: arkham-horror

The card '[Mists of Releh](http://www.arkhamhorrorwiki.com/Mists_of_Releh)' allows you to pass an evade check upon succesfull cast. Should your attempt to cast the spell fail, can you then proceed to do a regular evade check or does it count as failing the evade check?

The exact wording is as follows:

> Cast and exhaust to pass an Evade check. The casting modifier is equal to the monster's Awareness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you certainly can.

From the [Arkham Horror FAQ](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Arkham_Horror/FAQs/Complete_Arkham_FAQ.pdf):

> Q: If you fail to cast Mists of Releh, can you still make the 
>   Evade check normally?
>
> A: Yes.